# Codeigniter Pagination and List.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, list.js

I am trying to get pagination and list.js (sort and search) to work with my table.

I have tried any advice I can find online, the pagination works correctly, and list.js works correctly search and sort works. But only on the items on that page. I.E I have 13 records and 5 per page, so 3 pages. List.js only searches and sorts the records on that page. Not on the pages that arent displayed.

**The code in my tickets controller is as follows**

```
$data['main_view'] = "tickets/index";

    //loading pagination library
    $this->load->library('pagination');


    $query = $this->db->get('tickets','5',$this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['tickets'] =  $query->result();
    //get all tickets
    $query2 = $this->db->get('tickets');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/helpdesk/tickets/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $query2->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_tag_close'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class=\"active\"><span><b>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</b></span></li>";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
```

**The code for my table view is as follows**

```
<div id="tickets">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" /> 

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class=table-danger>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="Title">
                Title                
            </th>

            <th class="sort" data-sort="Creator">
                Creator              
            </th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="Date">
                Date             
            </th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="SLA">
                Service Level Agreement              
            </th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="Status">
                Status        
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
        <?php
               foreach($tickets as $ticket):?>
                <?php if($ticket->sla == 1){ ?>
                <tr style='background-color: #e6dfcb;'>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Title'><a href = '". base_url() ."tickets/display/".$ticket->ticket_id ." '>". $ticket->ticket_title. "</a></td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Creator'>". $ticket->ticket_creator. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Date'>". $ticket->ticket_date_reported. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'SLA'>". 'Elevated'. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php if($ticket->Status == 0){
                        echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Open'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 1){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Hold'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 2){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Awaiting End User'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 3){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Resolved'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 4){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Closed'. "</td>"; }
                            else{
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Unknown'. "</td>"; }?>      
                <td><a class = "btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/edit/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td> 
                <td><a class = "btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/delete/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>        
                </tr>
                <?php }
                elseif($ticket->sla ==2){?>
                <tr style='background-color: #e6cbe6;'>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Title'><a href = '". base_url() ."tickets/display/".$ticket->ticket_id ." '>". $ticket->ticket_title. "</a></td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Creator'>". $ticket->ticket_creator. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Date'>". $ticket->ticket_date_reported. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'SLA'>". 'Contract'. "</td>"; ?>                
                <?php if($ticket->Status == 0){
                        echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Open'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 1){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Hold'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 2){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Awaiting End User'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 3){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Resolved'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 4){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Closed'. "</td>"; }
                            else{
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Unknown'. "</td>"; }?>
                <td><a class = "btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/edit/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>                 
                <td><a class = "btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/delete/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>        
                </tr>
                <?php }
                else{?>
                <tr>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Title'><a href = '". base_url() ."tickets/display/".$ticket->ticket_id ." '>". $ticket->ticket_title. "</a></td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Creator'>". $ticket->ticket_creator. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'Date'>". $ticket->ticket_date_reported. "</td>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<td class = 'SLA'>". 'Basic'. "</td>"; ?>
                    <?php if($ticket->Status == 0){
                        echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Open'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 1){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Hold'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 2){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Awaiting End User'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 3){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Resolved'. "</td>"; }
                            elseif($ticket->Status == 4){
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Closed'. "</td>"; }
                            else{
                                echo "<td class = 'Status'>". 'Unknown'. "</td>"; }?>
                <td><a class = "btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/edit/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td> 
                <td><a class = "btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url();?>tickets/delete/<?php echo$ticket->ticket_id?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>        
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                endforeach;        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul class ="pagination"></ul>
<?php   echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

**My JS in the footer is as follows**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/list.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var options = { 
      valueNames: ['Title', 'Creator', 'SLA', 'Date','Status']

      page: 3,
pagination: true
    };

    var tickets = new List('tickets', options);

</script>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: _"Only pagination works when combined"_ - So what actually happens? You need to properly explain the issue. Does it sort wrong? Not at all? Search doesn't find anything? Find the wrong results? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: When combined. Pagination works as should. List.js does not sort in any direction and search doesn’t work either. Thanks.

Comment: Correction to above comment^, when combined list.js search and sort works. But only on the items on that page. I.E I have 13 records and 5 per page, so 3 pages. List.js only searches and sorts the records on that page. Not on the pages that arent displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that list.js requried exisiting pagination to work. However, list.js does every thing on its on. So i removed all my codeigniter pagaition and it is working perfectly.

For anyones reference in the furture my controller now looks as so

```
 public function index() {



    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $status =  $this->user_model->get_privileged($user_id);
    $privileged = $status->privileged;

    //calling the get tickets function from ticket model.
   if($privileged == 1){ $data['tickets'] = $this->ticket_model->get_tickets();}
   else {
       $data['tickets'] = $this->ticket_model->get_all_tickets($user_id);





   }
    $data['main_view'] = "tickets/index";


    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);



}
```

And my JS in the footer as follows

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/list.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">


        var options = {
          valueNames: ['Title', 'Creator', 'SLA', 'Date','Status'],
        page:6,
        pagination: true
      };

      var tickets = new List('tickets', options);

</script>
```